# Css is very unresponsive

Tags: css

I am making this project, but when I resize the window the css goes all over. I do not know how to make it responsive while maintaining the look I want

I have tried switching the units to rem but it still does not work

Here is the CSS:

```
    color: whitesmoke;


}
p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:15px;

    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
#space_background{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    z-index:-1;
    min-height: 100%

}
h1{
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
#planet{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

#send{
    display:block;
    margin-left: 45vw;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    /* position: relative; */
    padding: 1vw 1.3vw;
    top: -30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(64, 240, 10, 0.795);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;

}
#send:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
#divSend{
    text-align: center;

}
#next{

    display:block;
    margin-left: 46.25vw;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw;
    top: -30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.795);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#next:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
#nextDiv{
    text-align: center;
}
#atmo{
    display:block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 9.5vw;
    margin-right: 1vw;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw;
    top: -30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.795);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#atmo:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#rot{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1vw;
    float: left;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw;
    top: -30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.795);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#rot:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
#core{
    display:block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 31vw;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw;
    top: -30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.795);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#core:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
#goldi{
    display:block;
    float: right;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw;
    top: -30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.795);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#goldi:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);+
}
#stable{
    display:block;
    float: left;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw;
    top: -30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.795);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#stable:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
#water{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw;
    top: -30px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.795);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#water:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#firstThree{
    margin-left: 9.5vw;
}
#lastThree{
    margin-left: 66vw;
    margin-top: -18px
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vitae Vinctum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="start_style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
  </head>
  <body>
  <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay muted loop id="space_background">
    <source src="imgs/Space_Background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <img src="imgs/background.jpg" title="Your browser does not support video">
  </video>
  <h1>The Search for Life Begins...</h1>
  <div>
    <img id="planet" src="imgs/planet.png">
  </div>
  <div id="nextDiv">
    <button id="next">Next Planet</button>
  </div>
  <div id="divSend">
    <button id="send">Send Expedition</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="atmo">Atmospheric Test</button>
    <button id="rot">Send Expedition</button>
  </div>
<div>
  <button id="core">Send Expedition</button>
  <button id="goldi">Send Expedition</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="stable">Send Expedition</button>
  <button id="water">Send Expedition</button>  
</div>
<div id="testResponse">
  <p></p>
  <p id="atmoText">test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>


  <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works at full resolution but as soon as the window resizes, it goes wack

Comment: "it goes wack" is too broad of an explanation of what is happening. Can you edit your question and turn your code into a snippet so we can see the results within the question? What exactly is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both width and max-width properties for one css object:

```
#planet {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

To make your objects responsive, you should use media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #planet {width: 100%}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 700px) {
    #planet {width: 75%;}
}

#planet {width: 50%;}
```

Comment: You can set any properties you wish for any screen size, and check it by resizing window. Note that there can be some differences how it will look at different browsers. You should import normalize.css:
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css
And you can use the css library such as bootstrap or materialize css which will make your work smart and easier)
https://getbootstrap.com
https://materializecss.com/